# How to add a variable width to an element or container, not fixed width?

Tags: css, html, width, css-position

I have question about positioning and variable width. I used:

```
*{
border: 1px dotted blue; /*indicator for where every element are positioned or spaced on the page*/
}
```

I used this on all elements to see where everything is positioned as I stated in the code comment. I noticed the default width is 100% for every element. I want to know how to set a variable width, not fixed width on the same line. So, that way when I add more text or content to an element or container, I don't have to keep changing the fixed width and move elements around a lot to align it. For example, my footer:

```
<div class="footer">
        <p id="copyright">&copy; 2013 Jaime Penzellna</p>

        <!--SOCIAL MEDIA-->
        <ul id="social_media">
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Instagram</li>
            <li>LinkedIn</li>
            <li>Codecademy</li>
            <li>Flickr</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Right now the social_media  tag is on a new line with a 100% width and so is the

copyright tag. What I want to do is take the **p** and the **ul** and put it on the same line without using fixed width, but a variable width so i can flexibly add more text and the width will increase based on that and decrease when I remove them. How do I do that?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `display: inline-block;`

Check http://jsfiddle.net/urRAK/1/